# Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 Panorama control missing

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to port my Windows Phone 7 app to a new Universal App project for Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1. I have installed VS2013 Ultimate and Update 2 RC (which includes the 8.1 SDK). I do not however understand why I can't use the Panorama control. Has it been removed?

```
1) Panorama is not supported in a Window Phone project  

2) The type "Panorama" was not found. Verify that you are not missing 
an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

3) Unknown type "Panorama" in XML namespace
http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `Hub` control.

[Windows Phone 8.1 for Developers – What controls are new](http://www.jayway.com/2014/04/08/windows-phone-8-1-for-developerswhat-controls-are-new-2/)

```
<Hub Header="My header">
    <HubSection Header="My sub header">
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid />
        </DataTemplate>
    </HubSection>
    <HubSection Header="My sub header 2">
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid />
        </DataTemplate>
    </HubSection>
</Hub>
```